# Flutter delete Directory file

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to delete file in `Directory`.
It is created like so.

```
final Directory extDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/video';
await new Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.mp4';
```

I want to delete this specific path so that app won't heavy. 
How can I do this?
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? What's wrong with https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/delete.html or https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/deleteSync.html

Comment: Thank you for comment. I wanted to ask how to delete specific path. How do I move to the directory?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You don't need to move to the directory. You pass the path to the `Directory` constructor:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
    final dir = Directory(dirPath);
    dir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
}
```

Comment: As I understand this approach leads to deleting of the whole directory. And FileSystemEntry.delete or File.delete includes reading file to memory. Because when instantiating the File object we are getting object with read file contents for path we send to constructor as a parameter. Is there any way to delete file directly without reading it to the memory first?

Comment: Only the file path is held by the created File, Directory, or FileSystemEntry instance. No content is read into memory without an explicit read command.

Comment: `dir.deleteSync(recursive: true);` does delete ios file too? @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Not sure what you mean with ios file. There are not different kinds of files. Flutter delegates file deletion to the OS anyway. There won't be any Flutter specific behavior.