# Deleting all files within firebase storage

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I have the following parent folder called RealEstates
[Parent folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQAaq.png)

it contains subfolders (folders names are equal to my markerID)
[Subfolders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1fKJ.png)

Each of the subfolders contains multiple images (random number of images)
[Example of multiple images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHZ15.png)

I want to delete a sub-folder with all its images
I have tried the following codes :

```
    _button("Delete", Colors.red, () {
    return _showDialog(
        _dialogContentDelete(() {

            FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
                        .child("RealEstatesImages")
                        .child(markerID)
                        .delete();
                        Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, "map");
                 }));
})
```

and I also tried this code :

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
                                    .ref()
                                    .child("RealEstatesImages")
                                    .child(markerID);
storageReference.delete();
```

Both threw this exception

> Exception has occurred.
>   PlatformException (PlatformException(deletion_error, Object does not exist at location., null))

I also tried this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551670/flutter-delete-directory-file)

```
final dir = Directory(FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("RealEstatesImages").child(markerID).path);
dir.delete();
```

it threw this exception

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path = 'RealEstatesImages/7oZTySMHEKEtVhzOoas5' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: I have the same problem!