# Remove a local JSON file by code in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, assets

I wrote an app that fills a database from a local JSON file, and the app doesn't use this file after that.
Is there a way to remove it by code (by deleting it for example)?
Thanks.

Comment: Read [this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-io/File-class.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551670/flutter-delete-directory-file).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not sure this can be applied on file in the asset.